# How to get PayUmoney merchant & salt key?

Tags: android, integration, payment, payu, payumoney

I am create android app with payment integration using PayUmoney.In PayUmoney.com
sign up & login then fill pan details and bank account number.Also they verified but still i am not get merchant & salt Key for 10 days.

Comment: are you able to login payU? if yes then contact support for the keys, if you are not able to get those from your login account.

Comment: able to login.then contact support they send mail on progress 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they will personally inform you about it as it is a confidential information , rather you have to log in to Pay u  and go to settings and their you will find the key and salt values , if not then try contacting them personally !

Answer (score 0):

While Registering in PayUMoney you can find the Merchant key and Salt key in integration part. Check [Integration Details Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZS7N.png).